# Why can't I use dot notation on React State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm creating a flashcard app and I'm currently trying to set the front side of the flashcard to some text from an API.

My state:

```
const [deckWithCards, setDeckWithCards] = useState([]);
```

`deckWithCards` is a deck of flashcards and it looks like:

```
{name: 'Test Name', description: 'Test Description', id: 3, cards: Array(4)};
```

When I do `deckWithCards.cards` I get:

```
[{id: 1, front: 'Front of card', back: 'Back of Card', deckId: 1}]
```

If I was to have 4 cards in a deck, I'll get an array with 4 of these objects with the corresponding data.

I need access to all of this information however, when I try to do `deckWithCards.cards.front`, I get "Cannot read property 'front' of undefined."

I also tried looping through the cards array like:

```
let arr = [];
let allCards = deckWithCards.cards;
for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
   arr.push(allCards.front);
}
```

This gave me: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined."

How do I gain access to the items in this cards array?

Helper functions:

```
export async function readDeck(deckId, signal) {
  const url = `${API_BASE_URL}/decks/${deckId}?_embed=cards`;
  return await fetchJson(url, { signal });
}

export async function listCards(deckId, signal) {
  const url = `${API_BASE_URL}/cards?deckId=${deckId}`;
  return await fetchJson(url, { signal });
}
```

How I set my State:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

      readDeck(deckId, abortController.signal)
      .then(setDeckWithCards)
      .catch(setError)

      listCards(deckId, abortController.signal)
        .then(setCards)
        .catch(error)

      return () => abortController.abort();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Use `deckWithCards.cards[0].front`

Comment: The error you are getting is very descriptive. The variable `deckWithCards.cards` is undefined. It might only happen at the beginning, but you should look into it. Try `console.log` it.

Comment: Looks like `deckWithCards.cards` is defined and an array but `deckWithCards.cards[0].front` would be ;)

Comment: @Dominik when I console log `deckWithCards.cards[0]`, it says: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Can you show me where you used setDeckWithCards() function?

Comment: Your issue will be because it's initially an empty array and you're trying to do stuff with it before the data is populated into the state. Before trying to do stuff with the cards data or rendering it or anything, check that `deckWithCards.cards` exists

Comment: I created my State, `deckWithCards` in App.js, and in another component, ViewDeck.js is where I used `useEffect` to initialize my state with the data. `deckWithCards.cards` returns and array of 4 card objects. My issue is that I can't access the items inside that array

Comment: If `deckWithCards` is an `object` then why are you initializing it as an `array` with `useState([])`?.  Looks like you are changing the type from an `array` to an `object` when you first call `setDeckWithCards`, so it's not going to work properly with the functions of either type.

Comment: @LindaPaiste `deckWithCards` being initialized as an object or array are identical when console logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a moment in time while your `useEffect` and your `fetch` are still running before you set the cards.  During that time, the value of `deckWithCards` is going to be the initial value that you provided in your `useState`.  Your component has to be built in a way where it can run properly and render properly with that initial value.  If the eventual value of the resolved deck is an `object`, then it makes no sense that your initial value is an empty array.

```
const [deckWithCards, setDeckWithCards] = useState([]);
```

I recommend that you set the initial state to `null` or `undefined`.  Before you access any properties on `deckWithCards`, you have to check that it has been set to an actual value.

```
const [deckWithCards, setDeckWithCards] = useState(null);
const allCards = deckWithCards ? deckWithCards.cards : [];
```

Here we check if `deckWithCards` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (not `null`).  If we have a deck, then we access the cards from the deck.  If it's still `null`, we use an empty array.  Either way, `allCards` will always be an `array` that you can `map`, loop through, etc.

```
const fronts = allCards.map( card => card.front );
```

```
return (
  <ul>
    {allCards.map( (card) => (
       <div className="card" key={card.id}>
          {card.front}
       </div>
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: that's it! Thank you so much. Because the delay after the API call I first returned an empty object which made my value undefined, and then the object of cards would show. With that conditional it won't run unless it's actually initialized to the object value. What a relief :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the first state is `[]`

```js
const [deckWithCards, setDeckWithCards] = useState([]);
```

So in the very first run I except that `deckWithCards` is an array with no property `cards`. This can trigger the error you're encountering.

Otherwise, if `deckWithCards` is an array of objects, then to access the cards of, let's say, first object, you need to enter `deckWithCards[0].cards`

If instead you are correctly setting the value of `deckWithCards` with an object as you described above, `deckWithCards.cards` should correctly return the excepted list of cards.

Comment: I attempted both ways. I am unable to do `deckWithCards[0]` but I can do `deckWithCards.cards` to return and array of 4 card objects. But trying to append either `[0]` or `.front` doesn't work.